# Unable to output instance variable in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using HAML in my RoR application.

I have the below code in my Welcome controller:

```
def index
  render :layout => 'homepage'
  @qotd = 'Today is Sunday'
end
```

In my index.html.haml file I am using:

```
%h1
  = @qotd
```

But in the output, I just see empty h1 tags, without the value of the variable qotd.

Wonder what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `render` before the `@qotd` assignment, you're telling the template to render, and **then** you're making the `@qotd` assignment. When the template renders, `@qotd` doesn't exist yet. **Swap those two lines in your action.**

```
def index
  @qotd = 'Today is Sunday'
  render :layout => 'homepage'
end
```